# Configure Git Source Control Provider For Development Team

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

I'm totaly newbie to Source Control idea, so please be kind.

My situation is that we are a development team which contains 2 developers and 1 designer.
We use Visual Studio 2010 and we need to use a Git as a Source Control.

I've installed **Git Source Control Provider** and **GitExtensions** using Extensions Manager on all machines.

But there is only one thing I don't get it, how can I configure every Git on every machine to find a central repositry where we can Push and Update all work in one place?
Does that mean everyone will take a **copy** of a solution into his own machine (Locally) and configure Git to a repositry OR are we going to run on the same solution?

Honestly, I have not found articles regarding this issue and how teams on same project on Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Git is distributed version control system means that whenever you clone a repository you can work on your copy and commit too. Once you done you can push the commits to remote repository.

Comment: Fine, how could we push our commits to a repositry (locally centralized)?

Comment: I would suggest to go through the Git documentation, here are couple of tutorials on this website. http://git-scm.com/documentation